# How to test Java app operating directly on external API

Tags: java, ruby, testing, junit, rspec

After comming from Ruby world, I'm having little problems doing TDD in Java. The biggest issue is when I have application that is just communicating with external API.

**Say I want to just fetch some data from Google Calendar**, or 5 tweets from some Twitter user and display it.

In Ruby, I don't have any problems, because **I can monkey-patch the API library in tests directly**, but I have no such option in Java.

If I think about this in terms of MVC, my model objects are directly accessing the API through some library. The question is, **is this bad design? Should I always wrap any API library in some interface, so I can mock/stub it in Java?**

Because when I think about this, **the only purpose of that interface would be to *simulate* (please don't kill me for saying this) the monkey-patch.** Meaning that any time I use any external resource, I have to wrap each layer in interface that can be stubbed out.

```
# do I have to abstract everything just to do this in Java?
Twitter.stub!(:search)
```

Now you might say that I should always abstract away the interface, so I can change the underlying layer to anything else. But if I'm writing twitter app, I'm not going to change it to RSS reader.

Yes, I can add for example Facebook and then it would make sense to have interface. But when there is no other resource that can be substituted for the one I'm using, than I still have to wrap everything in interfaces to make it testable.

**Am I missing something, or is this just a way to test in the Java world?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using interfaces is just generally good practice in Java. Some languages have multiple inheritance, others have duck typing, Java has interfaces. It's a key feature of the language, it lets me use

1. different aspects of a class in different contexts and
2. different implementations of the same contract without changing client code.

So interfaces are a concept you should embrace in general, and then you would reap the benefits in situations like this where you could substitute your services by mock objects.

One of the most important books about Java best practices is [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective). I would highly suggest you to read it. In this context the most important part is **Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces**. Quote:

> More generally, you should favor the use of interfaces rather than
>   classes to refer to objects. **If appropriate interface types exist, then parameters, return values, variables, and fields should all be declared using interface
>   types.** The only time you really need to refer to an object’s class is when you’re
>   creating it with a constructor.

And if you take things even further (e.g. when using dependency injection), you aren't even calling the constructor.

One of the key problems of switching languages is that you have to switch the way of thinking too. You can't program language x effectively while thinking in language y. You can't program C effectively without using pointers, Ruby not without duck typing and Java not without Interfaces.

Comment: Sure (sorry for the delay)! I don't think that "Item 52" in Effective Java says that developers should *create* separate Java interfaces for every class, as you seem to imply. Note the part which says "If appropriate interface types exist ...". When they *don't* exist, it's perfectly fine to use the implicit class interface. *Separate* interfaces should not be abused.

Comment: No, not for every class (obviously not for entities and other value holders, also not for helper classes), but I do suggest that all service classes should be backed by interfaces (because you don't want tight coupling in services and you want the possibility to pass in mocks or proxies and frankly: because that's what interfaces were made for).

Comment: Normally, I don't make my service classes implement a separate interface, simply because of the fact that said interfaces tend to never get a second implementation. (I don't count "mock" implementations, because that is only *one* particular implementation strategy for mocking - and a poor one.) To me, separate interfaces are mainly meant to support the plugability of alternate implementations (real ones in production code, that is) for stable abstractions.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the external API is the way I would do this.

So, as you already said, you would have an interface and two classes: the real one and the dummy implementation.

Yes, it may seem unreasonable from the perspective of some services indeed being specific, like Twitter. But, this way your build process doesn't depend on external resources. Depending on external libraries isn't all that bad, but having your tests depend on actual data present or not present out there on the web can mess up the build process.

The easiest way is to wrap the API service with your interface/class pair and use that throughout your code.

Comment: But why go to the trouble of creating a wrapper when it adds no value? Just like in Ruby, in Java we can also provide mock/stub implementations for *any* class, when writing unit tests.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't say that it doesn't "add value" since it does exactly what is needed. Now, the other concern you pointed out is the extra effort, however you neglected the fact that my answer is available from plain Java, without any extra dependencies. Why would I go through the extra effort of obtaining an extra dependency and worrying about its compatibility, licence... stuff.. if I can simply do this.

Comment: Would you wrap, say, the Apache Commons Email API? It already wraps the more complex Java Mail API and is very easy to use (merely instantiate `SimpleEmail`, set a few properties, and call `send`). Clearly, no extra value in yet another layer of indirection over that. Regarding the extra effort of using a mocking library, why not, if it saves more than it costs? (I can guarantee the extra effort in writing mocks/stubs by hand is significantly larger for any realistic number of unit tests.)

Comment: Oh yes.. and wrapping is not useful for testing. It also decreases coupling, which is particularly important for external services. It is wrapper that is being used though the rest of the code. So, if (read: when) the service provider changes something, the only diff you have to make would hopefully have to be applied just to the wrapper. Depending on external services is the worst possible coupling I've seen so far.

Comment: You do make a point here! But, please note that  Apache Commons Email API is just a library, while Twitter API or, say, Adwords API are also external services. I would most certainly wrap them.

Comment: I am not advocating against use of mock objects for testing. I just think that what I described is the simplest thing that could possibly work in this scenario.

Comment: Well, external services should have *published APIs*, which are contracts not meant to be broken without good reason.

Comment: Yes. In a perfect world. In reality, this might not be the case. And even if the reason is good enough the problem stay, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you want are [Mock objects](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest.html).

As you described it, one of the ways one can generate "test versions" of objects is by implementing a common interface and using it.

However, what you are missing is to simply extend the class (provided that it is not declared `final`) and override the methods that you want to mock. (NB: the possibility of doing that is the reason why it is considered bad form for a library to declare its classes final - it can make testing considerably harder.)

There is a number of Java libraries that aim in facilitating the use of Mock objects - you can look at [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html).

Comment: Yes I can extend it, but that requires to have another layer that will pass the "API" object (mocked version in tests) to the model. But I guess there's no way around that.

Comment: Well, in that case, you could either use a factory method to create the object, or you could replace the private field in your model by using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito is more handy and like your ruby mocks.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* "monkey-patch" an API in Java. The Java language itself does not provide specific means to do it, but the JVM and the standard libraries do. In Ruby, developers can use the [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org) library for that. In Java, you can use the [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit) library (which I created because of limitations in older mocking tools).

Here is an example JMockit test, equivalent to the `test_should_calculate_value_of_unshipped_orders` test available in [Mocha documentation](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/examples/stubba.html):

```
   @Test
   public void shouldCalculateValueOfUnshippedOrders()
   {
      final Order anOrder = new Order();
      final List<Order> orders = asList(anOrder, new Order(), new Order());

      new NonStrictExpectations(Order.class)
      {{
         Order.findAll(); result = orders;
         anOrder.getTotalCost(); result = 10;
      }};

      assertEquals(30, Order.unshippedValue());
   }
```